# Trying to display the value of three select dropdowns when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to append the values of all three drop down selects into a span off to the side.  I can't seem to grab the values of the all three select boxes and insert them into the right place.

HTML:

```
<select id="single">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<select id="double">
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>

<select id="triple">
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add-btn button">Add</a>

<span class="results">Results: </span>
```

JS:

```
function displayAds() 
{
    var single = $('#single').val();
    var double = $('#double').val();
    var triple = $('.#triple').val();  
    $("span.results").last().append().html(single + double + triple);
}


$(".add-btn").click(function() 
{   
    displayAds();
});
```

Comment: You didn't give any argument to `append`, so what is it appending?

Comment: $('.#triple').val(); <-- You need to remove the "." in the selector and you need a parameter to append. e.g.: $("span.results").append(single+double+triple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML - no need href="javascript:void(0);"

```
<select id="single">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
<select id="double">
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
</select>
<select id="triple">
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
</select>
<a href="#" class="add-btn button">Add</a>

<span class="results">Results: </span>
```

Javascript - no sure how you define `adSize` `expType` `adType`

```
function displayAds() {
    // Get selected value for each select box
    $('select').each(function () {
        $("span.results").append($(this).val());

    });
}

$(".add-btn").click(function () {
    displayAds();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. `var triple = $('#triple').val();` You have a `.` in front of your ID selector, remove that.
2. `$("span.results").last().html(adSize + expType + adType);` You call an empty `append()`, `append()` takes an argument of an element, I believe you just want to set the `html`.

Comment: These things will definitely contribute to the breakage of your JS. Also, it seems that the variables that you want to append are defined as single, double, and triple, but called as adSize, etc...? Also note that `double` is a [reserved word](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) in javascript and should not be used for a variable name.